# ValidationMessagerFor and AddmodelError not working

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validationmessage

For the life of me I cant figure out why this simple piece of code is not working.  I know there are many questions like this here and I 've tried all of them, but I just cant get it to work!

My controller:

```
 //validate email
            if (studentlist.StudentLiveId == null || !studentlist.StudentLiveId.Contains("@"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("StudentLiveId", "Please enter a valid email id");
                return View(studentlist);
            }
```

My View - Relevant bit:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; color: red">
            hELLO
        </p>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentLiveId)
        </div>
```

The error:

> If I leave the liveid field null , instead of showing an error and
>   stopping, it just skips over the Live Id validation field and goes to
>   some other dropdown field in the model and throws a Object reference
>   not set to instance of an object error!

I am just printing the validation error in another common place and not next to the relevant field. I expect the view to throw the error and stop loading further and not go to the dropdown and show some random error. What is wrong here?

Comment: you are checking model state?

Comment: can you post comlete action and view?>

Answer (score 0):

The model gets processed and bound to the view regardless of whether there are any `ModelState` errors, so your expectation is unfortunately incorrect.

If you're getting a null reference error, it usually means you're trying to rebind a collection of some sort to a `DropDownList` or some other helper that doesn't have a guard against a null collection.

You have to remember that anything not bound to an input of one sort or another doesn't get retained when you post the form. It seems counter-intuitive at times, but the value bound to a dropdownlist is the "selected" value, not the collection of items used to populate the `<select>` element. So, if your initial action included logic to build an `IEnumerable`, `List`, or `SelectList` (etc.) for your model, you have to repeat that logic in your post action prior to returning the view.